# How to slideDown a new DIV using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

i want a jquery code which create a div contains a given content and then slide it down.

currently i have this code :

```
var newdivcontent = //ajax code here to bring new content
var newdivname = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
$("#topofpage").after("<div id='"+ newdivname+"'>"+newdivcontent+"</div>");
$(newdivname).hide();
$(newdivname).slideDown("slow");


<div id="topofpage">Real Time Posts: <br></div>
```

but it's just creating div and not doing slidedown.

thank you

Comment: What doctype are you using? "<br>" is not valid xhtml.  Have you tried to validate your html?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Online demo: http://jsbin.com/oroha

```
$("<div>").html("New Data").insertAfter("#topofpage").hide().slideDown("slow");
```

Comment: +1 The additional selections are redundant and can be skipped like shown here.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have given your div an integer as an ID - which won't be valid, and JQuery won't be able to access it by ID. And you need a '#' selector to tell JQuery that you're trying to access a single element by id. Try this:

```
var newdivcontent = //ajax code here to bring new content
var newdivname = "somediv_" + Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
$("#topofpage").after("<div id='"+ newdivname+"'>"+newdivcontent+"</div>");
$('#' + newdivname ).hide();
$('#' + newdivname ).slideDown("slow");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the div hidden using HTML and then just using slideDown:

```
var newdivcontent = //ajax code here to bring new content
var newdivname = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
$("#topofpage").after('<div id="'+ newdivname + '" style="display: none;">' + newdivcontent + '</div>');
$('#' + newdivname).slideDown("slow");

<div id="topofpage">Real Time Posts: <br></div>
```

The two animations probably aren't resolving in order as you expect them to (that's why they have callback functions) so it isn't looking right.

You also need to use the right selector in your hide/show calls, namely it needs to include the # before the div's ID in the selector.

Comment: Also recommend changing the newDivName to something that doesn't start with a number, as other answer recommends. I don't see how it could be the exact same, though, as in this you're hard-coding the div to be hidden to start :P If anything it would just never show.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
$('#newdivname').hide();
$('#newdivname').slideDown("slow");
```

*EDIT: I meant this:*

```
$('#'+newdivname).hide();
$('#'+newdivname).slideDown("slow");
```

but jacerhea already gave that

Comment: *"but jacerhea already gave that"* -- well, there's a "delete" link... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change your selectors to specify that it is an id attribute like so...

```
$("#" + newdivname).hide();
$("#" + newdivname).slideDown("slow");
```